# ALTER DATATYPE of Postgres table's column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just started working on Postgres database and created few tables .For convenience initially, I used character varying(50) but now I want to change that to Date (dd/mm/yyyy) format.

I tried using this command

`ALTER TABLE ip_role ALTER COLUMN event_dt TYPE date USING(event_dt::date);`

also this-

```
ALTER TABLE ip_role ALTER COLUMN event_dt TYPE DATE using to_date(event_dt, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

but not getting the error as-

`invalid input syntax for type date: "event_dt"`

Comment: and the error?.. bad value for the date?..

Comment: updated the error in question @VaoTsun

Comment: try my answer - does DMY help?..

Comment: Do `SELECT event_dt::date FROM ip_role;` and `SELECT to_date(event_dt, 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM ip_role;` work? (If not, maybe check that there are no stray tabs, spaces or newlines in the `event_dt` field.)

Comment: The error `invalid input syntax for type date: "event_dt"` - suggests that `event_dt` is being interpreted as a literal rather than a column-name. This could happen, e.g., if 1) one of the rows in your table has the string value "event_dt" for that column, or 2) you actually wrote `USING ('event_dt'::date)` instead of `USING (event_dt::date)`.

Answer (score 0):

alter (changing datestyle to properly read dates):

```
t=# create table d2(t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into d2 select '2017-05-08';
INSERT 0 1
t=# set datestyle to YMD, ISO;
SET
t=# alter table d2 alter column t type date using t::date;
ALTER TABLE
```

you don't keep dates in some date format:

```
t=# select * from d2;
     t
------------
 2017-05-08
(1 row)
```

, thus to see the wanted format, use:

```
t=# set datestyle to DMY, SQL;
SET
t=# select * from d2;
     t
------------
 08/05/2017
(1 row)
```

Comment: for the query `alter table ip_role alter column event_dt type date using event_dt::date;`
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "event_dt"

Comment: after changing to `set datestyle to DMY;`?.. then you have invalid date - post you data sample

Comment: `netflow=# set datestyle to DMY;`
`SET`          `netflow=# alter table ip_role alter column event_dt type date using event_dt::date;`
`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "event_dt" `        the data sample for event_dt column-     2017-05-08

Comment: updated the answer to be more informative - does it help?

Comment: actually datatype of event_dt column is character varying(50) and i want to change it to DATE Data type.